# Windows Azure UploadFromStream No Longer Works After Porting to MVC4 - Pointers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-storage

Updated my MVC3/.Net 4.5/Azure solution to MVC4.
My code for uploading an image to blob storage appears to fail each time in the upgraded MVC4 solution.  However, when I run my MVC3 solution works fine.  Code that does the uploading, in a DLL, has not changed.

I’ve uploaded the same image file in the MVC3 and MVC4 solution.  I’ve inspected in the stream and it appears to be fine.  In both instance I am running the code locally on my machine and my connections point to blob storage in cloud.

Any pointers for debugging?  Any known issues that I may not be aware of when upgrading to MVC4?
Here is my upload code:

```
        public string AddImage(string pathName, string fileName, Stream image)
    {
        var client = _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        client.RetryPolicy = RetryPolicies.Retry(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        var container = client.GetContainerReference(AzureStorageNames.ImagesBlobContainerName);

        image.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var blob = container.GetBlobReference(Path.Combine(pathName, fileName));
        blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

        blob.UploadFromStream(image);

        return blob.Uri.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I managed to fix it. For some reason reading the stream directly from the HttpPostFileBase wasn't working. Simply copy it into a new memorystream solved it.
My code

```
public string StoreImage(string album, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {   
        var blobStorage = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobStorage.GetContainerReference("containerName");
        if (container.CreateIfNotExist())
        {
            // configure container for public access
            var permissions = container.GetPermissions();
            permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;
            container.SetPermissions(permissions);
        }

        string uniqueBlobName = string.Format("{0}{1}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Path.GetExtension(image.FileName)).ToLowerInvariant();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueBlobName);
        blob.Properties.ContentType = image.ContentType;
        image.InputStream.Position = 0;
        using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.InputStream.CopyTo(imageStream);
            imageStream.Position = 0;
            blob.UploadFromStream(imageStream);
        }

        return blob.Uri.ToString();           
    }
```